# Partitioning a Data Set into Train and Test based on multiple class features in r

Tags: r, feature-extraction, feature-engineering

I have 5 categorical variables(v1-v5) and 1 numeric variable(v6) which have more than 6 categories each, I want to split the whole data into Train(70%) and Test(30%).

I've been facing this problem from quiet sometime, since I was using categorical variables and I was using random sampling. Every-time I split the data I face some issue with one of those variables. As the Data Levels are not same or missing a data level in the Test set when I predict here I'm building a model using Decision Tree.

It would be of great help if you can suggest me some smart way of tackling such issue.

I've gone through many stack overflow questions but hasn't come across question similar to mine.

Sample Data:

```
    v1    v2      v3    v4    v5    v6  Target_var
cat-1   cat-5   cat-8   1   Level-1  2    1
cat-2   cat-6   cat-8   2   Level-2  2    1
cat-3   cat-5   cat-9   3   Level-3  3    0
cat-1   cat-6   cat-8   2   Level-1  3    0
cat-2   cat-5   cat-9   3   Level-1  5    1
cat-3   cat-7   cat-10  1   Level-2  6    0
cat-4   cat-5   cat-8   1   Level-1  6    1
```

Sample Code:

```
set.seed(101)
dt <- sort(sample(nrow(total_data), nrow(total_data)*.7))
train<-total_data[dt,]
test<-total_data[-dt,]

#build decision tree models for testing purpose
tree <- rpart(Target_var~ ., data = train, method = "class")
pred.tree <- predict(tree, newdata = test, type = "class")
```

Error:

> xlev = attr(object,  : factor v3 has new levels

Comment: With that sample data set I do not get an error.  Can you provide  a minimal dataset (preferably using `dput`) that produces an error?  Or, if the above sample data does produce this error for you can you provide the output of `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: The data which I have is kind of confidential, that is the reason why I shared some sample data, updating the sample code

Comment: That is fine, but you could perhaps find a small subset of the data the reproduces the error and then randomize it or otherwise obfuscate it to protect the confidentiality.  To be clear, are you getting the above error when creating the dataset with the code shown, or when validating the model?  If the former, this is usually caused by some sort of corruption of the data occurring while slicing and dicing.  If the latter, you will need to sample in such a way that all levels are included in both training and test sets.

Comment: sorry I didn't update my question earlier, updated now with exact code. yes the issues comes when i'm trying to predict and it throws an error saying the levels are not same in training and testing level.

Comment: Oooh.  I get it now.  See [this related post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29446/random-forest-how-to-handle-new-factor-levels-in-test-set)  on stack validated (different machine learning algorithm but same issue).  Your options seem to be (1) stratified sampling to make sure all levels of all factors are accounted for in test and training set, (2) remove any rows of test set with levels not in training set, (3) set any observations in training set with levels not in test set as "NA".  Those last two may impact interpretability of test results. Option 4: wait for smarter answer =)

Comment: Make sure that you convert all the possible factor variables to `factor` type in the total dataset. The model needs to know that a factor "xyz" exists even though the train sample or test sample might be missing a single observation containing the factor level "xyz".

Comment: @Eric: Yes, I'm doing something similar, wanted to know if there is any better option,

Comment: @TUSHAr: I did convert all the features explicitly before giving to model

Comment: You should execute something like `total_data <- as.data.frame(lapply(total_data,as.factor))` (here all columns will be converted to 'factor') before splitting your dataset in train/ test. This is what @TUSHAr meant by his comment.

Comment: yes I did the same, I ran the above command. It means that you are explicitly converting the factors before giving to model right?

Comment: No. I meant that you should perform above line of code immediately before splitting data in train/ test. Can you provide `dput(total_data)`? Also can you pls update your code with proper `set.seed` so that the exact error message can be reproduced (the current code is not able to do so!).